# How to handle invalid cast from Observable Collection to Generic LIst

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, observablecollection

I am trying delete from a Gridview.

```
if (this.gridView.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}

ObservableCollection<Query> itemsToRemove = new ObservableCollection<Query>();

foreach (Query item in this.gridView.SelectedItems)
{
    itemsToRemove.Add(item);
}

foreach (Query item in itemsToRemove)
{
    //this line causes the invalid cast
    ((ObservableCollection<Query>)this.gridView.ItemsSource).Remove(item as Query);

    Code = item.CODE;
}
```

Removal of items from the Gridview

Invalid cast exception
Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Inventory.Query]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Inventory.Query]'.

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that `this.gridView.ItemsSource` is a `List<Query>`. You're trying to cast it to something it isn't. Simple solution: Cast it to what it really is.

```
((List<Query>)this.gridView.ItemsSource).Remove(item);
```

`itemsToRemove` doesn't need to be an ObservableCollection, by the way, because you aren't giving anybody a chance to observe it. No harm done, but you might as well have created that as a `List<Query>` instead.

Comment: That did it. I needed a list.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `Query` items to `itemsToRemove` but you should remove them from the `ItemsSource` collection which apparently is a `List<Query>`.

This should work:

```
var items = this.gridView.ItemsSource as List<Query>;
foreach (Query item in itemsToRemove)
{
    if(items.Contains(item))
        items.Remove(item);

    Code = item.CODE;
    this.gridView.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

Note that you will have to re-assign the `ItemsSource` property since a `List<T>` doesn't raise any notifications when items are added or removed.